# For-loop through 2 lists in Python to remove matches

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

I have two list i want to loop through in Python to find matches and remove them.
The first one is called SavedWordData and it's length is 2156 and the second one is called listReturned and it's length is 1000.

So then I try to do this:

```
maxLenReturned = len(listReturned)
maxLenSaved = len(savedWordData)

    for i in range(maxLenSaved):
    for x in range(maxLenReturned):
        if savedWordData[i] == listReturned[x]:
            savedWordData.pop(i)
```

But when I do this I get an error-message that says:
***IndexError: list index out of range***
Which indicate that I go outside the range of some of the lists, but I don't understand why and which of the lists I go outside it's range?

Comment: If you call pop() on a list, it decrements its size. Hence it raises the exception.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur Hmm okay. How can I achieve the same thing I want to do without doing the pop?
Should I do a new temp list where I store all the data that doesn't match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call pop() on a list, it decrements it size, so suppose you have a list of size 100 and you've popped 50 elements.When you try to fetch 51st element it raises `Index out of range` error, because now size is reduced to 50.

You should learn about list comprehensions. They are really awesome, you can get things done in a single line.

```
savedWordData = [x for x in savedWordData if x not in listReturned]
```

That's it. All those items that are in `listReturned` are not present in `savedWordData`.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this useful answer.
Will also read up on list comprehensions since it seems really awesome to know about.